MSBuild, VS2022 error with empty "\ref\" folder : error CS0006
I was converting a project from .net6 to .net8 and when I switched back to the .net6 version I can no longer build because its looking for generated dlls in an empty folder '\ref' although something is generating a '\refint' folder too.
I have deleted all the bin/obj, .vs directories. Cleaned, rebuilt but I still keep getting this error on all the dlls. Feels like the tooling is off somehow.
Has anyone has this '\ref' issue before?


After a tip to go through the output and check the first [project to fail with a missing dll I found a project that had not been built in debug. After that everything fails.
Recompiling that related project in debug started the dlls being written out to the ref folder.
Not a great error message but I thinl I'm sorted now

This Compiler Error CS0006 says,

The program was compiled and explicitly passed the name of a file that contained metadata; however, the .dll was not found.

As you found "a project that had not been built in debug" that caused the problem. For this kind of the issue, i suggest you can assign dependencies to projects to change the build order. In your case, you can assign the dependency (the project that had not been built to your project.
In Solution Explorer, select a project. On the Project menu, choose Build Dependencies > Project Dependencies. In the Depends on field, select the check box of any other project that must build before this project does.
For more information. please read Create and remove project dependencies
